# TypeError: node.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Not sure why I am suddenly getting this error

```
    var main_svg =  d3.select("#level_0")
                   .selectAll("path")
                    .data(data, 
                         function(d){ 
                              return (d && d.key) || d3.select(this).attr("id"); 
                         });
```

While it works fine on js fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/50/

Svg and datasets are same, but the same code does not run on my local computer

the line throwing error seems to be this one

```
function(d){ 
    return (d && d.key) || d3.select(this).attr("id");
}
```

Comment: Could you paste you js fiddle test, so we can understand better your error?

Comment: @Pablo: Sure see above

Comment: @lmo What error are you getting?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am getting: 
TypeError: node.getAttribute is not a function d3.js:646:1

Comment: I don't think that this is causing the error. If the fiddle is working, there has to be some other thing which is broken. Try to strip your code down as much as possible. Get rid of any unnecessary lines like adding texts, event handlers, colors, irrelevant attributes, replace callbacks with static values, until you are able to narrow the error down to the very line. I bet, it won't be the one which has come under suspicion.

Comment: @Imo did you find the reason?

Comment: in my case d3.select(this)  `this` - is supposed to be the `d` the element that I wanted to select which was returning null earlier. solved now.